# osx - diskwarrior error code (4010:716)

Tags: error

Issue:

- using diskwarrior 5.0
- when opening the app then authenticating i get an 4010:716 error. Trying to understand why and how to fix it.

Tried:

- removing the app
- reinstalling the app
- removing all references of the app from the library and reinstalling.
- used that on another computer and the app works fine.